# What is the keyboard shortcut to set the language for text in MS Word 2011?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

I usually write in English, but I often quote things in other languages like German or French. I know that you can set the language, like the font under Tools -> Language. Is there a keyboard shortcut to make this easier?

Comment: You can go to System Preferences > Keyboard and setup shortcuts for nearly anything. If change this preference does not show up, You can use an automator service

Comment: @thebro21 that did the trick! I should have thought of that. I found that Ctrl+Option+Cmd +L worked well for this on word (ie. No conflicting shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and there will be various shortuc setups for almost anything. If you see something that is not listed, Make a service in Automator and add it as shortcut:

[image]
Here you see the service in Automator. It ain't always have to be an AppleScript. You can chose other services from the Menu on the left.

[image]
And here is a screenshot of enabling the service and assigning a shortcut by double clicking the shortucts on right, and pressing a combination of keys.

---

[here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/tut01/index.html) is a full tutorial on services and automation as a little bonus to the question.